# Best way to add a dynamic amount of elements to a form?

Tags: ajax, xhtml, forms, webforms

I have a complex form that has a static section and one that can have from 0 to many divs that containing radio buttons, textfields and textareas.

I'm wondering what's the best way to add elements to the section that has a variable amount of form inputs. I have a working solution, but it's probably not the best:
I use javascript to add a chunk of html code and append it to the div containing the variable amount of input fields. In the code sample below, my javascript code would do something like

Javascript

```
document.getElementId('dynamic_form_stuff').innerHTML += "<div id='element3'>Form stuff</div>";
```

HTML

```
<form>
  <div id="static_form_stuff">
    form fields
  </div>

  <div id="dynamic_form_stuff">
    <div id="element1">
      Radio buttons stuff
      Text field stuff
      Text area stuff
    </div>      
    <div id="element2">
      Radio buttons stuff
      Text field stuff
      Text area stuff
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this largely depends on what you are doing elsewhere, and how many items you are adding, as well as how you want to add event handlers.

I tend to find it easier to use the DOM methods if I need to add event handlers, but if you are just adding to a form with a submit button, then using `innerHTML` is faster, as shown here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So I guess I'm in one of those situations of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" ? It just didn't look right and kinda hard to maintain.

The solution shown by sAc (below) was cleaner in a way but just as confusing as I have many elements (tables, inputs, images, etc.) that would go in the div "elements3". I'd have a bunch of elements to create and append.

Comment: It depends if you are adding event handlers, or how fast you want it to render.  There are trade-offs here.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do something like:

```
var elem = document.getElementId('dynamic_form_stuff');
var div = document.createElement('div'); // create element
div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');  // define attributes
elem.appendChild(div);
// and/or more code.....
```

This gives me more control in adding attributes and style there.

Comment: Style should be done by css, and it is easy to add that while using innerHTML, but more control is a good thing, as long as you don't mind it taking longer to render.